# Using SSL without Certificate Validation - Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: postgresql, ssl, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to AWS Postgresql, which is SSL enabled, but I use Non validating factory parameter. Usually When I do this using any other client, I specify this parameter

```
ssl=TRUE&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

But unfortunately I am not able to do the same with Oracle SQL developer. I keep getting this error when I modified the hostname to have these parameters. - `Status : Failure -Test failed: The SSLSocketFactory class provided org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory:/ could not be instantiated.`

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer, updating here in case if anyone facing the same issue. I just changed the hostname to have these parameter and added '&' at the end.

Something like this,

```
yourhostname:portname/databasename?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory&
```

Comment: Okay am I crazy or does this make absolutely no sense? I really appreciate that you found this but it's making me doubt my sanity.